# How to enable input for additional keys

Tags: javascript, html

I've copied this piece of code form [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/M02D3)

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}


function isCharKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The goal of them is to only allow input of either numbers or only textcharacters into an input field. I just discovered this also excludes functional keys like `del` and `backspace`. How would I add them here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key code for delete and backspace is 46 and 8 respectively. So you can create and modify the existing function

```
function allowDelBack(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 46 || charCode ===8)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the charcodes for the keys you want to exclude/include. One place to check the right ones is this website by Wes Bos: http://keycode.info/

Comment: Nice site, you might also like https://keyjs.dev which has a bit more information about the different events and properties. 

Answer (score 0):

You should not listen for keyboard events (`keydown` / `keypress` / `keyup`) to filter out certain characters, as the value of the input can also be updated by pasting or dropping text into it and there are many exceptions you should not prevent, such as arrows, delete, escape, shortcuts such as select all, copy, paste... so trying to come up with an exhaustive list of the ones that should be allowed is probably not a good idea.

Instead, just listen for the `input` event and update the input value removing all invalid characters while preserving the cursor's position:

```js
const inputDigits = document.getElementById('inputDigits');
const inputNoDigits = document.getElementById('inputNoDigits');

inputDigits.oninput = (e) => {  
  const cursorPosition = inputDigits.selectionStart - 1;
  const hasInvalidCharacters = inputDigits.value.match(/\D/);

  if (!hasInvalidCharacters) return;
  
  // Replace all non-digits:
  // See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_digit_non.asp
  inputDigits.value = inputDigits.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  
  // Keep cursor position:
  inputDigits.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
};

inputNoDigits.oninput = (e) => {  
  const cursorPosition = inputNoDigits.selectionStart - 1;
  const hasInvalidCharacters = inputDigits.value.match(/\d/);

  if (!hasInvalidCharacters) return;

  // Replace all digits:
  // See http://w3schools-fa.ir/jsref/jsref_regexp_digit.html
  inputNoDigits.value = inputNoDigits.value.replace(/\d/g, '');
  
  // Keep cursor position:
  inputNoDigits.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
};
```

```html
<input id="inputDigits" type="text" placeholder="Digits only" />
<input id="inputNoDigits" type="text" placeholder="Anything but digits" />
```

Here you can see a similar answer and example for a slightly more complex behaviour to allow only numbers with one single decimal separator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084513/3723993