# How to allow only English letters in input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, validation

So, this is my input field:

```
<input type={type} name={name} />
```

How can I allow only English letters?

This is the `RegEx`, I believe I should use: `/[A-Za-z]/ig`

https://regex101.com/r/upWFNy/1

I am assuming that `onChange()` event should be used for this with the combination of `setState()` and `event.target.value`.

Thanks.

**PS. I need to have this WHILE typing.**

Comment: It is already outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144167/only-allow-english-characters-and-numbers-for-text-input

Comment: @KevinLewis, hi. Can you update your answer, but only for English, no numbers please? Thanks.

Comment: English is an interesting language because it uses many letters are that aren't in its "alphabet". So, are you sure you want this? If so, perhaps you should restate it as upper and lowercase [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) letters.

Comment: Note: You can't tell a web browser what characters to allow or not allow. But you can use JavaScript or HTML patterns that are triggered upon various events to remove unwanted characters. This is what you'll see in the answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would try this `onChange` function:

```
onChange={(e) => {
  let value = e.target.value

  value = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/ig, '')

  this.setState({
    value,
  })
}}
```

See the codepen: https://codepen.io/bozdoz/pen/vzJgQB

The idea is to reverse your regex matcher with `^` and replace all **non**-A-z characters with `''`

Comment: Yes.. but for me the issue is that `value` is always empty. It fills dynamically as I enter the text. That's why it fails at `value={this.state.value}` @bozdoz

Comment: For jQuery, use `$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/ig, ''))`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the pattern attribute in your input.

```
    <input pattern = “[A-Za-z]”>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the Regx to solve this issue. Just check the character that entered is an alphabet using regx. If not then don't update the state value.

```
import React from "react";

class InputValidationDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      type: "text",
      name: "username",
      value: ""
    };
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    const re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value))
      this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { type, name, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type={type} name={name} value={value} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default InputValidationDemo;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-only-letters-qyf2j

> The important part is the regular expression. You can change your
> validation type by changing the regex.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, all characters except ascii 0-127 which are English characters should be excluded, o through 127 also gives you space, +, -, / and punctuation which is useful, if you want only letters then [^A-z] should do the trick, if you need non-space characters then [^A-z\s] should work:

```
document.getElementById('english').addEventListener('input', function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]+/ig, '');
});
```

React Way:

```
class InputEnglish extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(e) {
    let val = e.target.value.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/ig, '');
    this.setState(state => ({ value: val }));
  }
  render() {
    return (<input 
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.onChange}
    />);
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVMgrd

Comment: Hi, can you write this in React way please?

Comment: @JohnSam don't do much in React but this should work.

Comment: @JohnSam take a look at the codepen in the post it works in there.  If it's still not working let me know. : )

Comment: Yes.. but for me the issue is that `value` is always empty. It fills dynamically as I enter the text. That's why it fails at fetching the `value`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `/[A-Za-z]/` regular expression and an `input` event handler which is fired every time the value of the element changes. Something like below:

```js
const regex = /[A-Za-z]/;
function validate(e) {
  const chars = e.target.value.split('');
  const char = chars.pop();
  if (!regex.test(char)) {
    e.target.value = chars.join('');
    console.log(`${char} is not a valid character.`);
  }
}
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', validate);
```

```html
<label for="myInput">Type some text:</label>
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

Comment: This won't work if I type, paste or drop invalid characters in the middle of the input. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065370/how-to-enable-input-for-additional-keys/64085268#64085268

Comment: @Danziger I tried pasting a non-letter character example on Chrome v 85 and it seems to work as I expect. Do you have an example of this not working in a specific browser?

Comment: It works fine if you paste it at the end. Try moving the cursor to the left and pasting it there. I'm on Chrome 85 as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
  alphacheck(e: any) {
    const regex = /[A-Za-z]/;
    const chars = e.target.value.split('');
    const char = chars.pop();
    console.log(char);
    if (!regex.test(char)) {
      e.target.value = chars.join('');
      alert("Please enter only alphabets");
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
     
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }


<input placeholder="Full Name" formControlName="fullName"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]*"  (keypress)="alphacheck($event)"  name="fullname" value="" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /[A-Za-z]/;
function validate(e) {
  const chars = e.target.value.split('');
  const char = chars.pop();
  if (!regex.test(char)) {
    e.target.value = chars.join('');
    console.log(`${char} is not a valid character.`);
  }
}
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', validate);
```

```html
<label for="myInput">Type some text:</label>
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).