# Enter only week days (1 to 7) in html input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form for week and days in which user can fill week no and days no (separated by comma).

In day field user have to enter days of week like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 2,5,7. I want to add validation to prevent number outside 1-7 range.

Or a calendar type pop up that contains number 1-7 and add number in text field when user click on number.

Comment: read the input, split on `,` convert to number, validate each number is in required range

Comment: Why you dont use a standard  date picker of bootstrap https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/date-picker/

Comment: Or use 7 checkboxes. Then you don't need to validate any user input, other than to ensure at least one was checked

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this will do. Add your "," code if needed (188)
https://keycode.info/

```
$('#text_field').keypress(function(e) {
        preventNumberInput(e);
    });


    function preventNumberInput(e){
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keyCode >= 49 && keyCode <= 55 ){
        // accept

    } else {

    }
}
```

**Edited**

Use this to prevent copy-paste

```
$('#text_field').on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: check the link to get the code number. You can do it! :-)

Comment: Technically this answer enables: !,@,£,$,%,^,& to be entered as they share the same keycode. Make sure to set the form field to number to ensure these symbols cant be entered.

Comment: This still allows you to enter whatever value you like by pasting

Comment: @DanielVickers, we can prevent these character by preventing shift key. like this: if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 51)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you have to write your else section. write this: e.preventDefault();

Comment: `preventDefault()` won't stop you pasting anything here; I can still use the mouse

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, please check edited answer. I have added how to prevent copy and paste.

Comment: Or, you could save all this messing around in JS and just use 7 checkboxes in HTML as I mentioned in the comment under the question.

Comment: @CarlosMartins Still a poor solution, as pointed out by @RoryMcCrossan. Also, what if instead of pasting I just drag & drop some other text into the input? Filtering input characters is usually done with the `input` event, not using KeyboardEvents such as `keydown`, `keypress` (which is also deprecated) or `keyup`, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065370/how-to-enable-input-for-additional-keys/64085268#64085268

Comment: Also, just in case you want to take a look at an alternative tool, check this out: https://keyjs.dev